# Barssince and bar processing in pine script question, problem and solution

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've had a really annoying bug/problem for a few hours and couldn't figure out what was happening with pine script barssince. I think I've figured out what was happening, I've found another way to do it but still have questions.

So my problem was fairly simple. I have code to find pivot points but obviously detecting a pivot lags so I only know n bars afterwards that it was a confirmed pivot. I then wanted to track the price in the opposite direction. Thus if I detect a high pivot (reversing to go down) I wanted to track the lowest price since the pivot. I thought simple:

```
low_price := ta.lowest(low, bar_index - high_pivot_index)
low_index :- bar_index - ta.barssince(low_price == high)
```

I created the values as var so they weren't time series. So the lowest function gives me the lowest price since the pivot bar and that worked fine. The barssince was intended to simply find where the lowest price was (bar index).

This didn't work. For a while I really struggled trying to work out what the problem was and why it wasn't working. "low_price" was a var float so I assumed that the barssince would use a flat/current value of low_price and find where it matched high (which is a time series). No.

I may be wrong but I eventually figured out that what I think is happening is that the barssince isn't calculated for the current bar and processed backwards it is processed on each bar and the result of the condition (ie "low_price == high") stored as a time series and when barssince is processed it simply looks at this already stored time series. Essentially each execution of barssince wasn't using the current value of price_low it was essentially looking at the condition "low_price[n] == high[n]" even though low_price is a var.

My solution was to scrap using lowest and barssince but the minor difficulty was having some separate code to deal with the bars between the actual pivot bar and the bar when the pivot is determined (confirmed). So in the code that detects the pivot I have code to find the low_price and low_index for the bar since the actual pivot with the lowest price. Then for all bars I have code:

```
low_index := (low < low_price) ? bar_index : low_index
low_price := (low < low_price) ? low : low_price
```

So this raises the question for me: is there a way to use barssince where the condition wants to compare a historical value to a current value - ie in my problem I wanted to compare "low" to my calculated var value.

I can think of many situations where I might calculate a value and then want to find the number of bars where some time series equalled that value.